# UITableView get titleForHeadersInSection swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, swift-playground, ios8.1

I want to set the title of the header in the section of UITableView. What is the syntax in **swift** to set the title of the header in the section.

```
func tableView( tableView : UITableView,  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)->String
{
    switch(section)
    {
    case 2:
        return "Title 2"
        break
    default:
        return ""
        break
    }

}

func tableView (tableView:UITableView , heightForHeaderInSection section:Int)->Float
{

    var title = tableView.titleForHeaderInSection[section];
    if (title == "") {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return 20.0;
}

func tableView (tableView:UITableView,  viewForHeaderInSection section:Int)->UIView
{

    var title = tableView.titleForHeaderInSection[section] as String
    if (title == "") {
        return UIView(frame:CGRectZero);
    }
    var headerView:UIView! = UIView (frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 20.0));
    headerView.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor;

    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the section number for comparing instead of the title?

Comment: actually I wants to know the syntax to get the title For Header In Section.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the func already defined in your class i.e. :

**self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)**

For example, using your code:

```
func tableView( tableView : UITableView,  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)->String {
   switch(section) {
     case 2:return "Title 2"

     default :return ""

   }
}

func tableView (tableView:UITableView , heightForHeaderInSection section:Int)->Float 
{

    var title = self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
    if (title == "") {
        return 0.0
    }
    return 20.0
}
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW, you don't need "break".

Comment: Removed the 'break's - left over from a cut and paste of a larger snippet :)

Answer (score 5):

In order to call this method you must use the UITableViews `titleForHeaderInSection` method.  This method will provide the index for the current section and you are required to return a String, the returned String will be set as the header.

In order to invoke this, lets assume we have an array of Strings called `cars`

```
cars = ["Muscle", "Sport", "Classic"]
```

We can then simply call

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? 
{
    // Ensure that this is a safe cast
    if let carsArray = cars as? [String]
    {
        return carsArray[section]
    }

    // This should never happen, but is a fail safe
    return "unknown"
}
```

This will return section titles in the order given above.

Answer (score 2):

**Update Swift 5**

**Xcode - 11.4**

```
func tableView( _ tableView : UITableView,  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)->String? {
   switch(section) {
     case 1:return "Title of section header"
     default :return ""
   }
}
```

This will show header in caps lock. To make it in regular mode as you want to show it use this method along with the above mentioned:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let titleView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    titleView.textLabel?.text =  "Title of section header"//titleView.textLabel?.text?.lowercased()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 0{
           return "Pass Your String For Header"
       }else{
          return "Pass Your String For Header"
     }
 }
```