# Swift UITableView with Custom Cell and Multiple Sections array data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My Scenario, I am trying to create `UITableView` with custom cell and multiple sections from single array. Here, I need to show different titles in sections. How to do this? I used below code but not able to get clear understanding.

My Code below

```
var  data = [["1","2","3"], ["4","5"]]
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}
```

Comment: you should implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView get titleForHeadersInSection swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27011131/uitableview-get-titleforheadersinsection-swift)

Comment: @dahiya_boy My scenario I am asking single array to add both data sections and row

Comment: What should be the title for each section?

Comment: @ PGDev I need to give some string titles. as of now you can provide some sample data. In future I am going to load JSON data into that. As of now mock data enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be 2 cases around it,

1. In case you simply want to add **`String` titles** to each `section`, implement `UITableViewDataSource's` **`tableView(_: titleForHeaderInSection:)`** method.
2. And if you want to give a **custom `view`** for each `section`, implement `UITableViewDelegate's` **`tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)`** method.

Here is an example with `tableView(_: titleForHeaderInSection:)`,

```
class VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    let data = [["1","2","3"], ["4","5"]]
    let sectionNames = ["This is Sec-1", "And this is Sec-2"]

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionNames[section]
    }
}
```

Do implement `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)` in case you need custom height for each `section`.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Edit:**

Use `accessoryType` as `.checkmark` for cell selection.

Create a custom `UITableViewCell` and `override setSelected(_:animated:)` method in that like so,

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        self.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
    }
}
```

Set the `reuseIdentifier` of `CustomCell` in `xib` as `cell`. Also, update the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method to dequeue `CustomCell` instance. I updated that in the code above.

Comment: Superw. Here I have one doubt If I want to load custom data into section. how to do that? within same array instead of count how to fetch custom data?

Comment: Fetch the custom section name using section parameter in titleForHeaderInSection method. I've updated the answer to show you can example.

Comment: I am sorry Can you please add check mark into your answer. Checkmark should be select one cell at a time.

Comment: That's a separate requirement.  You should ask a separate question for that.

Comment: Updated the answer. Enjoy.. 